# $ \left( ||T^n||\right)^\frac1n \leq ||T|| $ as $n\to\infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Given an operator $T\in B(X,X)$, I'm trying to prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( ||T^n||\right)^\frac1n \leq ||T|| $$

I can show that $||T^n||\leq||T||^n$, but only for finite $n$. How can I be sure that this holds in the limit? I'm a bit confused as to what kind of continuity that would require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that for all finite $n$ we have $ \| T^n \|^{1/n} \leq \| T \|.$ Recall that if $a_n\to a$, $b_n \to b$ and $a_n \leq b_n$ then $a\leq b.$ Hence, if $\lim_{n\to\infty} \| T^n \|^{1/n}$ exists, then it is less than or equal to $\| T\|.$ The limit does indeed exist - Gelfand's formula tells us that it is the spectral radius of $T.$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to prove. The inequality
$$
\|T^n\|^{1/n}\leq\|T\|
$$
is trivial, since $\|T^n\|\leq\|T\|^n$ by the Banach-norm inequality.

What is not trivial is to show that your limit exists and it agrees with the spectral radius. Every proof I know uses some form of complex analysis, and it appears in every functional analysis book.

Comment: Thanks. So it's more complicated than I first thought.

Comment: Like I said, I have never seen an elementary proof that the limit exists. In fact, the proofs I know use Banach-space valued analytic functions, and reducing their arguments to the usual analytic functions is not obvious (to me, at least).

Comment: @Belen The proof [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) is elementary.

Comment: @RagibZaman: but that proof would only work for a finite-rank operator.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Ahh yes, sorry about that.